# "Resource not found or temporarily unavailable" error in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could
>   have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "Null";
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Welcome to the first application of MVC</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

firstcintroller.cs

```
namespace mvcapp.Controllers
{ 
    public class firstController : Controller
    {
        // GET: first
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what URL are you trying to visit? (I'd strongly recommend using a more conventional bracing style, and following .NET naming conventions, btw.)

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: firstcintroller.cs? Change the name this file yournameController

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the controller name is “first” in yout RouteConfig.cs file in App_Start folder.

And, create a folder with name “first” file in Mvc\Views folder and place Index.cshtml inside first folder and execute the project.

For more information, find below URL:

[ASP.NET MVC Page Won't Load and says "The resource cannot be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893552/asp-net-mvc-page-wont-load-and-says-the-resource-cannot-be-found)